# How to register one of two possible event handlers with onYoutubeiframeAPIReady event on WordPress site

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, iframe, youtube-iframe-api

I have am having an issue with a wordpress site that displays Youtube videos inside an iframe. The issue is that sometimes the iframe will load, and other times it won't. After digging around I found that there are two definitions of the onYoutubeiframeAPIReady method. One of these methods is defined in a giant javascript file (named plugins.js) that includes several other possibly important javascript functions. This file resides in the parent theme.The other is defined inside a script tag in the DOM, and this one appears to work when I can get it to run. The mechanism that decides whether it runs or not is still a bit mysterious to me but I have found that disabling the cache in the network console tab or hard refreshing (Ctrl+Shift+R) will cause this script to run and eventually display the video as expected.

What I would like to know is what tools are there to ensure that the desired function definition is called instead of the other one?

I have tried disabling caching on the server side and inside wordpress, but only disabling the cache on the browser seems to work and this is not a permanent fix. I researched whether or not the parent theme had settings available to include or remove certain scripts. It does not. I have also successfully (the video loads) dequeued the plugins.js script and replaced it with a copy that does not include the defective onYoutubeiframeAPIReady method, but this is not a permanent solution either and is bad practice from a WordPress perspective (please convince me otherwise if I'm wrong). Last thing I've tried is to leave plugins.js alone, but also enqueue a new script that just contains the javascript that does work. This doesn't appear to work.

I am just really mystified as to how the browser decides which one of these two methods to register with the onYoutubeIframeAPIReady event, and also how would disabling the browser cache allow the in document script (which works) to run.

The problematic script from parent theme:

```
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    YTplayers = new Array();
    jQuery('.no-touch .uncode-video-container.video').each(function() {
        var playerY;
        if (jQuery(this).attr('data-provider') == 'youtube') {
            var id = jQuery(this).attr('data-id');
            options = jQuery(window).data('okoptions-' + id);
            options.time = jQuery(this).attr('data-t');
            playerY = new YT.Player('okplayer-' + id, {
                videoId: options.video ? options.video.id : null,
                playerVars: {
                    'autohide': 1,
                    'autoplay': 0, //options.autoplay,
                    'disablekb': 1,
                    'cc_load_policy': options.captions,
                    'controls': 0,
                    'enablejsapi': 1,
                    'fs': 0,
                    'modestbranding': 1,
                    'origin': window.location.origin || (window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.hostname),
                    'iv_load_policy': options.annotations,
                    'loop': options.loop,
                    'showinfo': 0,
                    'rel': 0,
                    'wmode': 'opaque',
                    'hd': options.hd,
                    'mute': 1
                },
                events: {
                    'onReady': OKEvents.yt.ready,
                    'onStateChange': OKEvents.yt.onStateChange,
                    'onError': OKEvents.yt.error
                }
            });
            YTplayers[id] = playerY;
            playerY.videoId = id;
        }

    });
}
```

The script in the DOM that works if only I could get it to run all the time:

```
<div id="steps">
    <div class="step">
        <div id="player"></div>
        <script>
            // create youtube player
            var player;
            function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
                player = new YT.Player('player', {
                    width: '1120',
                    height: '630',
                    videoId: '<?php echo $videoID; ?>',
                    playerVars: {
                        'autoplay' : 0,
                        'controls' : 0,
                        'showinfo' : 0,
                        'rel' : 0,
                        'fs' : 0,
                    },
                    events: {
                        onReady: onPlayerReady,
                        onStateChange: onPlayerStateChange
                    }
                });
            }

            // autoplay video
            function onPlayerReady(event) {
                event.target.playVideo();
            }

            // when video ends
            function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
                if(event.data === 0) {
                    window.location.assign('https://someurl.com');
                }
            }
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

The script responsible for calling onYoutubeIframeAPIReady (link to full script [here](https://www.youtube.com/s/player/8a298c38/www-widgetapi.vflset/www-widgetapi.js)):

```
 "undefined" != typeof YTConfig && YTConfig.parsetags && "onload" != YTConfig.parsetags || En();
    var bo = A.onYTReady;
    bo && bo();
    var co = A.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady;
    co && co();
    var eo = A.onYouTubePlayerAPIReady;
    eo && eo();
```

[This](https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api?ver=5.9.3:formatted) script loads the script above:

```
var scriptUrl = 'https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/s\/player\/8a298c38\/www-widgetapi.vflset\/www-widgetapi.js';
try {
    var ttPolicy = window.trustedTypes.createPolicy("youtube-widget-api", {
        createScriptURL: function(x) {
            return x
        }
    });
    scriptUrl = ttPolicy.createScriptURL(scriptUrl)
} catch (e) {}
if (!window["YT"])
    var YT = {
        loading: 0,
        loaded: 0
    };
if (!window["YTConfig"])
    var YTConfig = {
        "host": "https://www.youtube.com"
    };
if (!YT.loading) {
    YT.loading = 1;
    (function() {
        var l = [];
        YT.ready = function(f) {
            if (YT.loaded)
                f();
            else
                l.push(f)
        }
        ;
        window.onYTReady = function() {
            YT.loaded = 1;
            for (var i = 0; i < l.length; i++)
                try {
                    l[i]()
                } catch (e$0) {}
        }
        ;
        YT.setConfig = function(c) {
            for (var k in c)
                if (c.hasOwnProperty(k))
                    YTConfig[k] = c[k]
        }
        ;
        var a = document.createElement("script");
        a.type = "text/javascript";
        a.id = "www-widgetapi-script";
        a.src = scriptUrl;
        a.async = true;
        var c = document.currentScript;
        if (c) {
            var n = c.nonce || c.getAttribute("nonce");
            if (n)
                a.setAttribute("nonce", n)
        }
        var b = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
        b.parentNode.insertBefore(a, b)
    }
    )()
}
;
```

Link to page in question: https://www.ttstaff.com/safety-orientations/general-industry-orientation/

TL;DR:
There are two onYoutubeIframeAPIReady() definitions loaded. One of them works and the other doesn't. I don't think I have the power to remove the defective one, but it's the one that seems to get run. So how can I force the one that works to run, even though the defective one is still loaded?

Comment: The first script of the parent definition runs on elements with the classes ".no-touch .uncode-video-container.video" and that it just the function definition mean that is not executed, and the second one runs on the element "player", so nothing to have one each other, and just a question, do you test this on browser or mobile?

Comment: I have tested on desktop only. The problem is that the ".no-touch .uncode-video-container.video" script is the only one that runs. If I set break points in both scripts, I can see that only the first runs. If I disable caching or remove the first one entirely the second one runs but not the first.

Comment: I think the reason that only one runs is that there is an event and only one version of onYoutubeIframeAPIReady can be registered to that event, but I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: Yes that can be a case, but know that I see in more detail, where are you executing the function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady, and if there is no problem why you no just change the name on the funciton if this in your reach?

Comment: It is technically within my reach but it's a WordPress quirk/feature where the file containing the "broken" script will be automatically updated and the function will be renamed back to onYoutubeIframeAPIReady, and I would therefore have to go back and manually rename the function for every update. WordPress provides ways to "override" javascript files, but (as far as I can tell) not individual functions.

Comment: I've also added links and snippets to the script that calls the onYOutubeIframeAPIReady method and the one that loads that one.

Comment: I've tested your website and yes the function that is damaging the player is the function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady on the plugins.js, and there comes the question why are you reusing the iframe api, you could insert the iframe directly and this ensures that loads independently of the youtube api, in your case will be: <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/RBcX3M_Gfdg" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>

Comment: Ok that could be a really straightforward solution. The only thing missing would be the page redirect when the onPlayerStateChange event is triggered. Is there a way to do that without trying to reuse the API?